# What happens if you cast the Animate Objects spell on an weapon affected by the Shillelagh cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, animated-objects

I was looking at the [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) cantrip, whose description states (emphasis mine):

> The wood of a club or quarterstaff **you are holding** is imbued with nature's power. For the duration, you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of **melee attacks using that weapon**, and **the weapon's damage die becomes a d8**. The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn't already. The spell ends if you cast it again **or if you let go of the weapon**.

And then looking at the [*animate objects*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) spell, whose description states:

> Each target animates and becomes a creature...

And later lists different object stat blocks, including their attacks.

A number of questions came to mind:

- Can you use your spellcasting ability for the animated object's
  attacks?
- Does *shillelagh* changing the damage die affect the *animated
  object's* statblock?
- And also, is this even possible? *Shillelagh* ends when you let go
  of the weapon (which is now a creature), and the rule on ["Moving
  Around Other Creatures"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures) states:

  > Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

**What happens when you cast *animate objects* on a weapon affected by *shillelagh***?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### You cannot cast *animate objects* on a weapon affected by *shillelagh*.

The description for [*animate objects*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) specifies:

> Choose up to ten nonmagical objects...

The description of [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) states:

> The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn't already.

Therefore a weapon affected by *shillelagh* is not a valid target for the *animate objects* spell.

Comment: You could conceivably cast Shillelagh on an animated object you were holding.  I don't *think* it would break the Animate Objects spell.  It wouldn't have any effect at all on the Animated Object stats, though - those are entirely independent of any weapon stats.

Comment: @BenBarden I would say you wouldn't be able to do it in that order either because it is no longer a weapon, but instead a creature. That would be like saying you can wield your gnome companion and cast barkskin and shillelagh on him.

Comment: @BCPowers Casting Barkskin on a gnome does not make them a club or staff.

Comment: @BenBarden And objects under the effect of animate objects are no longer weapons.

Comment: @BCPowers I assert that that's "DM ruling" territory, rather than being clearly determined one way or the other.  "gnome with barkskin" is a much clearer case.

Comment: @BenBarden I concur... but I'm pretty sure a gnome does become a club when picked up by a bugbear or goliath. ;)

Comment: @T.J.L. okay, that's a fair interpretation... but it doesn't become a club or staff *made of wood*.

Comment: @BenBarden True enough.

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn't be able to cast it.

Shillelagh ends if you let go of the weapon

> The spell ends if you cast it again or **if you let go of the weapon**

Animate Objects

> Objects come to life at your command. Choose up to ten nonmagical objects within range **that are not being worn or carried**.

To cast shillelagh, you need to be holding the weapon.
To cast animate objects, you can't be holding the weapon.

Comment: I read the first line, and I was goign to ask what this answer added to the issue, but no - this is actually really stylish.  +1.  It even feeds into the other answer, because if you do it in the reverse order, the item is already magical, and shillelagh won't stick.